# Trim specific leading and trailing characters from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that contains a path

```
str = "/example/path/with/different/trailing/delimiter\"
```

and I want to trim the leading and trailing `/` and `\`. What is the best practice in Python 3?

Currently I'm using

```
trimmedPath = str.strip("/\\")
# trimmedPath is "example/path/with/different/trailing/delimiter" as desired
```

Two questions:

1. Is this the best trim function for trimming specific characters in Python 3?
2. Are there specific path functions for such operations in Python 3 so I don't have to set the delimiters manually?

Comment: `strip` (and `lstrip` and `rstrip`) is/are the python version of trim.  As @pmuntima mentions, the `os.path` library has lots of useful path functions if we knew more about your particular application.  You could probably use `os.path.join`, or `os.path.relpath` to combine or obtain a path in the format you're looking for.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is the pythonic way. It is usually the case when there is a builtin function.

There are a few builtin path manipulators available in the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) library. You might want to use them if one of the manipulators is a match for your use case.

Answer (score 26):

Example of `strip()` in action; in this case, removing a leading plus sign:

```
In [1]: phone_number = "+14158889999"

In [2]: phone_number.strip('+')
Out[2]: '14158889999'
```