# How to strip special characters from the start and end of the string in python

Tags: python

I have a list of sentences which consist of special characters(!?@#$.) at the end of the string. I need to strip them. Here is the list of sentences:

```
['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring.', 'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2.', 'It will change your view of the matrix.', 'Are the human people the ones who started the war?', 'Is AI a bad thing?']
```

My output should be like this:

```
['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring', 'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2', 'It will change your view of the matrix', 'Are the human people the ones who started the war', 'Is AI a bad thing']
```

Comment: what is the definition of "special characters"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim specific leading and trailing characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026036/trim-specific-leading-and-trailing-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: Updated my question @WasiAhmad

Comment: Looks like you want `[i[:-1] for i in my_strings]` if every string has a special character

Comment: Super!! @chrisz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to remove characters from the beginning and the end, you could use the `string.strip()` method.

Example:

```
strp_chars = '!?@#$.'
sentence = 'The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring.'
print(sentence.strip(strp_chars))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `string.strip` with all of the characters you need removed, in a list compression, e.g.:

```
In [1]: l = ['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring.', 'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2.', 'It will change
   ...:  your view of the matrix.', 'Are the human people the ones who started the war?', 'Is AI a bad thing?']

In [2]: p = [i.strip('.,?!') for i in l]

In [3]: p
Out[3]:
['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring',
 'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2',
 'It will change your view of the matrix',
 'Are the human people the ones who started the war',
 'Is AI a bad thing']

In [4]:
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try translate method :

```
import unicodedata
import sys

data1=['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring.', 'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2.', 'It will change your view of the matrix.', 'Are the human people the ones who started the war?', 'Is AI a bad thing?']


data=dict.fromkeys([i for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P')])

def remove_punctuation(sentence):
    return sentence.translate(data)

for i in data1:
    print(remove_punctuation(i))
```

output:

```
The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring
Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2
It will change your view of the matrix
Are the human people the ones who started the war
Is AI a bad thing
```