# Remove special characters if they are at the beginning of a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Given a string `___abc_de`

I want to remove `_` character if it is at the beginning of the string.

So the above string should be `abc_de`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026036/trim-specific-leading-and-trailing-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 5):

Use `str.lstrip()`:

```
In [28]: s = "___abc_de"

In [29]: s.lstrip('_')
Out[29]: 'abc_de'
```